# How to implement language support for JavaFX in FXML documents?

Tags: java, xml, javafx, fxml

How can I have different languages for a view in a FXML document to support many countries?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`ResourceBundle`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) to store the locale-dependent text, and access the data in the bundle using `"%resourceKey"`.

Specifically, create text files for each language you want to support and place them in the classpath. The [Javadocs for `ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) have the details on the naming scheme, but you should have a default bundle defined by `BaseName.properties` and bundles for other languages and variants defined by `BaseName_xx.properties`. For example (with the `resources` directory in the root of the classpath):

resources/UIResources.properties:

```
greeting = Hello
```

resources/UIResources_fr.properties:

```
greeting = Bonjour
```

Then in your FXML file you can do

```
<Label text = "%greeting" />
```

To pass the `ResourceBundle` to the `FXMLLoader` do:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.UIResources");
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/path/to/FXML.fxml"), bundle);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

This code will load the resource bundle corresponding to the default locale (typically the locale you have set at the OS level), falling back on the default if it can't find a corresponding bundle. If you want to force it to use a particular bundle, you can do

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/resources/UIResources", new Locale("fr"));
```

Finally, if you need access to the resource bundle in the FXML controller, you can inject it into a field of type `ResourceBundle` and name `resources`:

```
public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources ;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I can't put ResourceBundle on the ContextMenu. Can you help me

Comment: In fact for those who still wonder, the bundle parameter is to be put in the call of the load method  or constructor as a second parameter!

Comment: @AlexandrePieroux Doesn't the answer explicitly say that? "To pass the `ResourceBundle` to the `FXMLLoader` do..."

Comment: In the example it actually pass the bundle to the getResource method. Just showing that there is a typo in the examples -> a parenthesis is missing right  before the coma.

Comment: @AlexandrePieroux Ah, I see. Thanks; I fixed it.

Comment: @James_D what if I need to pass a parameter? if I have in bundle key=translation {1}, how do I use that in the fxml?