# Uses of URL & ResourceBundle in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

What is the purpose of URL & ResourceBundle in the following code

```
public class HelloWorld implements Initializable  {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the javadoc of interface [Initializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html)?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch i read it, but could understand nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation for the [Initializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) interface:

> NOTE This interface has been superseded by automatic injection of location and resources properties into the controller. FXMLLoader will now automatically call any suitably annotated no-arg initialize() method defined by the controller. It is recommended that the injection approach be used whenever possible.

You should use something like this instead:

```
public class Controller
{
    @FXML
    private URL location;
    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    public void initialize()
    {
      // do your setup stuff here
      // fxml loader will call this for you
    }
}
```

Additional note: The above quote calls for a 'suitably annotated no-arg initialize() method'. If for whatever reason you require a private initialization, make sure you 'suitably annotate' it with the @FXML annotation.

Comment: can you please give an example of private URL location; & private ResourceBundle resources; usage

Comment: 1. 'location' is the location of the .fxml file. 2. 'resources' can be used to use strings of different languages: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325403/how-to-implement-language-support-for-javafx-in-fxml-documents